# On octobercms static pages plugin render a group of fields with a repeater inside

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend, octobercms-viewbag

On "content/static-pages/index.htm" i can see the saved fields that can be rendered on page:

Then on partials i can use {{ data.section_color }} to render a field.

Now i want to create a repeater field inside "meta/groups.yaml" like this:

```
carousel2:
  name: Carousel2
  description: Carousel2
  icon: icon-file-image-o
  fields:
    section_carousel2:
       type: repeater
       prompt: Add new subitem
       form:
          fields:
            section_carouselimage2:
              label: Image2
              type: mediafinder
              mode: image
            section_carouseltitle2:
              label: Title2
              type: text
            section_carouselsubtitle2:
              label: Subtitle2
              type: textarea
              size: small
```

I can see the field on my backend and i can save data with it. On "content/static-pages/index.htm" now i have:

```
[viewBag]
title = "Home"
url = "/"
layout = "static"
is_hidden = 0
navigation_hidden = 0
sections[0][section_carousel2][1][section_carouselimage2] = "/carousel/bg-1.jpg"
sections[0][section_carousel2][1][section_carouseltitle2] = "Carousel2 Title"
sections[0][section_carousel2][1][section_carouselsubtitle2] = "Carousel2 Subitle"
sections[0][section_carousel2][2][section_carouselimage2] = "/carousel/bg-2.jpg"
sections[0][section_carousel2][2][section_carouseltitle2] = "Carousel2 Title2"
sections[0][section_carousel2][2][section_carouselsubtitle2] = "Carousel2 Subtitle2"
sections[0][_group] = "carousel2"
==
```

The problem is that i can't find a way to render this field. How can i render repeater field inside repeater group? How can i render for example "section_title2" field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, lest assume that you are adding **carousel2**

ok we added it's markup in the **meta/groups.yaml** so basically we are making **carousel2** group.

so now solution , how we show its information/data.

> first we need to create partial in cms **blocks/carousel2** so carousel2 will be placed in blocks folder where other partials are (simple / react / etc ...).

ok now we need to add this content inside it

```
<section>
  <!-- render inner section -->
    {% for slide in data.section_carousel2 %}
        <!-- this block will repeat / based on added slides( so probably slider markup will be here) -->
        <p>{{ slide.section_carouselimage2 }}</p>
        <p>{{ slide.section_carouseltitle2 }}</p>
        <p>{{ slide.section_carouselsubtitle2 }}</p>        
    {% endfor %}
</section>
```

ok now you can access all fields inside for loop. we used loop because your group is repeater.

**let's understand it a bit.**

---

> data : = this variable is passed to each partial. its data regarding your group, in our case its **carousel2**

now data has **2 things**  **first** : ***group name*** , **second** our ***real data*** which we saved in page.

to get that saved data we can use **data.section_carousel2** now as we know its type of repeater so to get that data we need to add for loop.

now in for loop we used **slide** variable which will get all data for all fields within repeater for each iteration.

> so now within this loop you have your fields **slide.section_carouselimage2** as we declared in **meta/groups.yaml** file.

If anything is not clear or if its not working please comment.

Comment: Εxcellent explanation. I missed the "data." inside for loop. Now is working. Thank you.